# Как реализовать INTERSECT в TypeORM с посдержкой take() и skip()

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, orm, typeorm

Мне необходимо реализовать фильтрацию продуктов в интернет магазине. При этом там предусмотренна пагинация.

Саму фильтрацию я сделал, но без потдержки пагинации.

Схема БД:
[image: Схема БД]

Моя реализация:

```
    async function (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
            try {
                const category = request.query["category"]
                delete request.query["category"]
                // delete request.query["limit"]
                // delete request.query["offset"]

                let data = await getConnection().transaction(async manager => {
                    return Promise.all(
                        Object.keys(request.query).map(attribute => {
                            let values = request.query[attribute]
                            if (typeof values === "string") values = [values]

                            return manager.createQueryBuilder(ProductEntity, "product")
                                .innerJoin("product.properties", "property")
                                .where(`product.categoryId = :category_id`, { category_id: category })
                                .andWhere(`property.attributeSlug = :attribute_id`, { attribute_id: attribute })
                                .andWhere(`property.valueSlug IN (:...value_ids)`, { value_ids: values })
                                .getMany()
                        })
                    )
                })

                // Костыль для реализации INTERSECT.
                let products = data.pop() || []
                if (data.length > 0)
                    products = products.filter(product => {
                        for (const set of data)
                            if (set.findIndex(part => product.id === part.id) === -1)
                                return false
                        return true
                    })


                return response.status(200)
                    .json(
                        products
                    );
            } catch (error) {
                next(error);
            }
        }
```

Однако данный метод не позволяет реализвать частичную выборку, необходимую для пагинации.

Также буду благодарен если Вы подскажете как оптимизировать данный код, а то мне не сильно нравиться потенциальные 100+ запросов в БД.

Comment: https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/using-pagination

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто собрать условия через `or`

```
import { getConnection, Brackets } from 'typeorm';

const query: Record<string, any> = {};
const { category, ...filter } = query;

const qb = getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder(ProductEntity, 'product')
  .where({ categoryId: category })
  .innerJoin('product.properties', 'property');

qb.andWhere(
  new Brackets((querybuilder) => {
    Object.keys(filter).forEach((attribute_id) => {
      const values = filter[attribute_id];
      if (values !== null && values !== undefined) {
        querybuilder.orWhere(
          `property.attributeSlug = :attribute_id and property.valueSlug IN (:...value_ids)`,
          { attribute_id, value_ids: Array.isArray(values) ? values : [values] },
        );
      }
    });
  }),
);

// .take().skip() или .limit().offset()
const items = await qb.getMany();
```